# Google Plus Share not working for dynamic title description and images

Tags: google-plus, share

I know similar question is asked multiple times but they do not have correct answers and none of them is working for me. I have trying to share my url, title and description on google+ but seems like its not working.

I tried everything given on the page - https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/

My web page has dynamic title, description and image but Google+ is not able to take all that information from Open graph parameters (og:image, og:title etc) provide

Following are my open graph parameters which will be filled during page load and I checked it through debugger, all the information is coming correctly.

```
    <title>this is test </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="description" content="this is test desc"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

    <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:image" content=""/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="" />
```

and the sharing link which I have been using is : https://plus.google.com/share?hl=en&url=xxxx

Can someone please suggest how will it work with dynamic contents?

Note: Open graph is not working for facebook also but I had to explicitly provide all parameters in share link of Facebook.

Comment: What debugger did you check that show it is working correctly? What makes you think the other questions do not have the correct answer?

Comment: Thanks abraham for your response. I used developer's tool (Firebug) and it shows me all updated information in Open graph tags. However Google+/Facebook both do not pick data from open graph tags. If you want to check this, visit http://vidstock.in/ and when you will click on any video, video will play in next screen and it will show share buttons. Facebook works fine because I explicitly provided data but Google+ wont work. This site is still in development state so bear with it :).

Answer (score 0):

Google+ Snippets do not work with dynamic apps. The info has to be returned in the HTML since Google's parser does not execute JavaScript.

Comment: So there is no way that user can share on Google+ ?

Comment: Users can share any page they want. However if you want to populate Google+ Snippets the URLs have to return HTML with the details already included.